# How can I convert $\dfrac{(x – 1)^{2}}{16} +\dfrac{(y + 2)^{2}}{9} = 1$ to polar form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I convert  $\frac{(x – 1)^{2}}{16} + \frac{(y + 2)^{2}}{9} = 1$to polar form?  This is an ellipse centered at $(1, -2)$.
I understand the general approach for converting between the coordinate systems.  However, in this case I got stuck on handling the terms $9x^2 + 16 y^2$.  Please provide sufficient details.  Thanks.

Comment: just plug in $x=r\cos\theta$ $y=r\sin\theta$

Comment: This suggestion will be fine if it is acceptable for you to leave the expression as a quadratic equation with a term of a trigonometric factor times $ \ r^2 \ $ and another term with a trigonometric factor times $ \ r \ $ equal to a constant.  If you want something in the form $ \ r \ = \ f(\theta\) \ $ , that may not be so tidy, since the polar coordinate system measures angle using the _origin_ as center.

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward method of converting from rectangular to polar coordinates produces

$$ \ 9 \ (x-1)^2 \ + \ 16 \ (y+2)^2 \ = \ 144 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 9x^2 \ - \ 18x \ + \ 9 \ + \ 16y^2 \ + \ 64y \ + \ 64 \ = \ 144 $$

$$\Rightarrow \ \ 9x^2 \ - \ 18x \ + \ 16y^2 \ + \ 64y \  = \ 71 $$

[basically, putting the ellipse equation into "general form" (for a conic section) first]

$$\rightarrow \ \ 9r^2 \ \cos^2 \theta \ - \ 18r \ \cos \ \theta \ + \ 16r^2 \ \sin^2 \theta \ + \ 64r \ \sin \  \theta \  = \ 71 $$

$$\Rightarrow \ \ r^2 \ ( \ 9 \ \cos^2 \theta \ + \ 16 \ \sin^2 \theta \ ) \ +  \ r \ ( \  64 \ \sin \ \theta \ - \ 18 \ \cos \ \theta \ )  \  = \ 71 \ \ . $$

This is a perfectly good polar equation.  Expressing this as an *explicit* function $ \ r \ = \ f(\theta) \ $ is not so easy to manage, however.

Graphing the polar equation above does produce the desired ellipse:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, RecklessReckoner, for your answer.  I will take this answer for now.  Wikipedia does provide the polar equation of a general ellipse.  But I don't know how to get there from the equation above.  Ref:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center.

An ellipse, centered at (r0, θ0), with the major axis rotated by ψ relative to the polar axis:
  r(θ) = [P(θ) + Q(θ)] / R(θ), 
where P(θ) = r0 * [(b^2 – a^2) cos(θ + θ0 – 2 ψ) + (a^2 + b^2) cos(θ – θ0)], 
 Q(θ) = (√2)ab√[R(θ) – 2 (r0^2) (sin(θ – θ0))^2], 
 R(θ) = (b^2 – a^2) cos(2θ – 2 ψ) + a^2 + b^2

Comment: The equation you are referring, which measures angle from the _center_ of the ellipse, can be obtained from **Apurv**'s answer.  That is using a differently defined angle from what is usually meant by "polar form".

Comment: @user150378 The other equation that you are describing in your comment, shown as "General polar form" in the Wikipedia article, is not likely to be what you are being asked to find if you are in a typical pre-calculus course. You would get it by making extensive use of trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 2):

Put $$x-1=4\cos\theta$$ and $$y+2=3\sin\theta$$

Hence the required form is $$(x,y)\equiv (1+4\cos\theta,-2+3\sin\theta)$$ Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Well, kinda... this isn't really _polar_ form, but a parametric form using an angle-parameter, referred to here as $ \ \theta \ $,  measured from the center of the ellipse, not from the origin.  One could use this as the start toward a polar function $ \ r \ = \ f(\theta) \ $ , with $ \ \theta \ $ being the angle measured from the positive $ \ x-$ axis with vertex at the origin, but it won't be pretty.